# Determine presence of "plateau" phase with lme4

Tags: r, linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to determine whether the data depicted in the following figure shows a plateau phase for higher scramblings.

[image]

As I have often been encouraged to use linear models instead of anova - I have decided to tackle this issue with lme4.

The output I get for my latex document from the [texreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) parser is as follows:

```
                     Model 1
```

(Intercept)              : 2.03    [1.78; 2.28]<sup>*</sup>

COIsc-14                 : -0.23    [-0.38; -0.08]<sup>*</sup>

COIsc-18                 : -0.23    [-0.38; -0.08]<sup>*</sup>

COIsc-22                 : -0.19    [-0.34; -0.04]<sup>*</sup>

COIsc-26                 : -0.32    [-0.47; -0.17]<sup>*</sup>

COIsc-6                  : 0.45    [0.30; 0.60]<sup>*</sup>

AIC                      : 1697.17

BIC                      : 1735.04

Log Likelihood           : -840.59

Deviance                 : 1681.17

Num. obs.                : 840

Num. groups: ID          : 7

Variance: ID.(Intercept) : 0.08

Variance: Residual       : 0.41

<sup>*</sup>0 outside the confidence interval

```
                     Model 1
```

My confidence interval is 0.95 . Can I make the point I am trying to make by the fact that the 14, 18, 22, and 26 values are all in each other's confidence intervals?

Also, what information do I get from

```
Variance: ID.(Intercept) : 0.08 

Variance: Residual : 0.41
```

? Does that mean that 0.51 of my variance is explained by my categories, 0.08 by my IDs (which I define as random) and 0.41 by unidentified sources? 0.41 sounds like a lot, is this a good model then?

Comment: I would consider trying successive difference contrasts (`contr.sdif` from the `MASS` package, via the `contrasts` argument), and see whether the parameters for the successive differences are all near zero. The variance components are variances, not proportions of variance. I don't think the proportion of variance at different levels says very much about the overall quality of the model ...

Comment: so the fact that the confidence intervals include each other's values does not sufficiently make the point?what would I use as `n` in contr.sdif? also, in the absence of any other possible model, how can I tell how "good" my model is? Can I read deviance and log likelihood in absolute terms? If so, what are good values for them?

Comment: I think it might make the point; depends how formal you want to be. `n` would be the number of categories in the factor, but I think if you just say `contrasts=list(COIsc=contr.sdif)` that should work OK. Deviance and log-likelihood don't give a measure of goodness of fit.  See http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#rsquared

Comment: ok, that sounds good. Is there anything in particular which I can read from the variance of my ID. (intercept) and the Residual? does that mean that very little variance is explained by the ID compared to the variance left unexplained? Why is there no mention of the variance explained by my actual factors of interest? Also, is there anything at all from this summary which I can take as a measure or hint that my model isn't complete nonsense? I was thinking that may be devaince because authors recommend testing `lme4::lmer()` validity by doing an analysis of deviance.

Comment: There is a "variance component" (the variance explained by the *fixed effect* predictors) that is not reported in the summary. The decomposition of variance is far less straightforward in mixed models than it is in the simple ANOVA world (where there is a unique orthogonal decomposition of the total sum of squares). If your predictions are reasonable and your estimated parameter values are not extreme (and variance components are all positive) you should be OK. You can calculate an R^2 value as described at the link in my previous comment ...

Comment: so practically I can interpret nothing from the variance values?